# Get resource id from typedarray

Tags: android

I have this file array.xml and I want to get the item value from an array.
How can I do that? I have tried with getInt but that returns 0. All help is welcome.

```
<resources>
    <array name="firstAd">
        <item>border_top_id_1v</item>
        <item>R.id.dugme_1v</item>
        <item>R.id.rent_or_buy_1v</item>
        <item>R.id.currency_1v</item>
        <item>R.id.price_1v</item>
        <item>R.id.name_1v</item>
        <item>R.id.address_1v</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change each item to @id/object instead of R.id.object, then change the tag from array to integer-array, and move the code to your 'integer.xml' resource file.

integer.xml:

```
<resources>
<integer-array name="firstAd">
    <item>@id/dugme_1v</item>
    <item>@id/rent_or_buy_1v</item>
    <item>@id/currency_1v</item>
    <item>@id/price_1v</item>
    <item>@id/name_1v</item>
    <item>@id/address_1v</item>
</integer-array>
</resources>
```

Then, programmatically use a TypedArray, like so:

```
TypedArray firstAd = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.firstAd);
int resourceId = firstAd.getResourceId(index, defValue);
```

Comment: Yes i did that, but i need to get the item

Comment: I tried that, it doesnt work. It expects a typed array

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that won't help

Comment: I updated my answer.. You won't be able to use "R.id" references in XML, but rather have to use the @id/ format.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: R.id.dugme_1v would be how you reference a resource ID programmatically i.e. in a .java file, whereas @id/dugme_1v is how you reference a resource ID in an XML file, i.e. in a 'values' resource file... see here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html      "Resources can be referenced from code using integers from R.java, such as R.drawable.myimage.
Resources can be referenced from resources using a special XML syntax, such as @drawable/myimage". It is just different syntax for XML (Resource) and Java (code) files.

Comment: Thank you my friend, now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

try @id/yourIDHere

```
    <item>border_top_id_1v</item>
    <item>@id/dugme/1v</item>
    <item>@id/rent_or_buy_1v</item>
    <item>@id/currency_1v</item>
```

Comment: i only need to get the item, i don't want to change the xml file